# File format JPEG/JPG

Tags: windows-10

In image resizer The extension that is created in this new version is JPEG, instead of JPG in the previous one. In certain programs, this extension JPEG is not recognized. Is it possible to have the output extension in JPG format?

Comment: You can change the file extension of any file, just change it from jpeg to jpg. You will have to change view settings in Folder Options to see extensions and change them.

Answer (score 0):

You can always rename the output file to .jpg after you get it. .jpg and .jpeg files have no difference, with the exception of the file extension.

If you need to rename multiple file extensions to .jpg, put all the jpeg in a folder, right click on the folder and open a command prompt window there.

Then, use `ren *.(current extension name) *.(extension you want)`

In your case, `ren *.jpeg *.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the extension via rename, please **uncheck the Hide extensions for known file types** option **Windows Explorer** -> **View** -> **Options** -> **Change folder and search options** -> under **View** tab, uncheck the **Hide extensions for known file types**. Then right click the image to rename it as ***.jpg

[image]